# Concordion reports - how to specify external resources root path?

Tags: testing, bdd, concordion

I have got a problem using `@ConcordionResources` annotation in my tests, when those are executed from-within test-jar by JUnit 5 Launcher API.

The problem actually lies in the way Concordion initializes root paths for static resources:

```
Enumeration<URL> resources = fixtureClass.getClassLoader().getResources("");
while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
     rootPaths.add(new File(resources.nextElement().toURI()));
}
```

So, basically, it is really problematic because Concordion unsuccessfully tries to operate on resources inside test-jar.

What I would like to ask, is there any system property or something like that, that can be used to set some external folder outside jar as a root path for those static resources?

Answer (score 0):

Discussed in [issue 278](https://github.com/concordion/concordion/issues/278), but the options are:

1. Create a Concordion Extension that implements this for the current version of Concordion
2. Wait for this to be implemented in Concordion v3.0.0
3. Create a PR that implements this and either build it locally, or use Jitpack to build from your PR branch.